# RXSwift App crashes When permission change from settings

Tags: ios, permissions, rx-swift

I have setup RX for photos permission like

```
extension PHPhotoLibrary {
    static var authorize : Observable<Bool> {
        return  Observable<Bool>.create { (observer) -> Disposable in


            if authorizationStatus() == .authorized {
                observer.onNext(true)
                observer.onCompleted()
            } else {
                requestAuthorization({ (handler) in
                    observer.onNext(handler == .authorized)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                })
            }


            return Disposables.create()

        }
}
```

In App Delegate I am asking for permission

```
    let authorized = PHPhotoLibrary.authorize.share()
    authorized.skipWhile{$0 == false}
        .take(1)
        .subscribe(onNext: {[weak self] (authorized) in
           // Nothing here
        })
```

Now When I start App permission dialogue appears which all working fine
But when I put app in **background** and from settings **manually toggle permission** and when I back to app again app **crashes**  :(

Any help appreciated

Comment: Could you provide some crash log?

Comment: @ChinhNguyen I find out it is not crash System restarts app when permission changed from settigns